# Check if the front desktop window path is inside the Desktop folder with AppleScript

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript

I have an issue with an applescript I have written. The script needs to check if the front desktop window path is inside the Desktop folder (i.e a prefix match.) This is the script:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set currentPath to (POSIX path of (target of front window as alias))
end tell
set thecommandstring to "echo \"" & currentPath & "\" | grep -q \"^/Users/host/Desktop/\" "
set grepResult to do shell script thecommandstring
```

However on executing it gives the error :

```
error "The command exited with a non-zero status." number 1
```

I am a total newbie with Applescript and must be making some very basic mistake. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well because it seems that my edits on adayzdone isn't accepted or anything I will post it in a new answer. His problem is that he does a string comparison with non string objects and therefore it doesn't work. It should be something like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set desktopPath to path to desktop as string
    set windowPath to (target of the front window as string)
    if windowPath begins with desktopPath then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: I didn' t want to post update until I got back in front of my computer tomorrow to test it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tell application "Finder"
set desktopPath to path to desktop
set windowPath to (target of the front window as alias)
if windowPath contains desktopPath then
    beep
end if
end tell
```

Comment: Note that as a file system reference, an alias is more than just the path, for example it still works even if the item is renamed or moved.  To check the paths, you will need to coerce the alias to text or otherwise resolve it in order to do a comparison.

Comment: Doesnt the contains account for that? Are you getting an error?

Comment: There is no error (well, as long as there is a Finder window), but your script will only get a match if the target of the Finder window is the Desktop.  If the target is another folder on the desktop for example, there will not be a match, even though the path of the target contains the path to the Desktop.  To get the desired results the paths will need to be resolved for the comparison (unless I am misunderstanding the question).